# .NET Core system exception localization not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, localization

What is the status and design regarding localization of system exception messages in .NET Core (.NET 5)? Are they supposed to be localized? Is there something like "language packs" that can be installed for the .NET Core runtime?

Localization/translation of system exception messages it not working in .NET 5.

I have the following code:

```
static void Main()
{
    var culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;

    var nre = new NullReferenceException();
    Console.WriteLine(nre);
}
```

This always produces English output (at least when running on Windows with English as the primary language) when running on .NET 5, no matter what I set the `CurrentUICulture` (or `CurrentCulture`) to.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This used to be different on .NET Framework, at least when the target language pack is installed. Here's what I get when I change `TargetFramework` from `net5.0` to e. g. `net462` in the `.csproj` file:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
```

I had a look into the [source code of the NullReferenceException class](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/NullReferenceException.cs) and it seems to be prepared for localization. At least it retrieves the error message from some StringResources. But up to now there are [only English resources available](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/Resources/Strings.resx). Or did I miss something?

Comment: This is more suitable to be an issue in dotnet/runtime repository.

Comment: I would like the answer for this question too. Wondering why on localhost I get Dutch error messages from a specific library, and on the live site only English error messages. I have tried to set the uiculture and language in a billion places, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet/issues/474 the .NET Core has no localized messages. Not sure if it will continue to be that way in .NET, but at least that explains the difference in .NET 5 responses.